# Why is Nginx serving `index.html` instead of a 404?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I have a site where requesting a particular JSON file and finding it missing triggers a request for a fallback JSON file. However, rather than getting a 404 for the first file, I was getting the contents of `index.html`, which isn't valid JSON and created an error.

I traced the problem to this directive:

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }
```

How can I get it to serve a `404` for `mysite.com/some/nonexistent/file.json`, but still get `index.html` for `mysite.com/`?

Answer (score 5):

After some reading, I changed the `try_files` directive:

```
# Old way: fallback to index.html
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

# New way: serve a 404 response
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Another option would be:

```
# Fall back to this error page
try_files $uri $uri/ error_pages/404.html
```

I still have this directive to handle serving `index.html` for `mysite.com/`:

```
server {
  # ...
  index index.html index.html;
  #...
}
```

Comment: So, you searched and found a solution within a minute. That's incredible!

Comment: @Pothi [Self answering is highly encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking); [rewarded even](http://serverfault.com/help/badges/14/self-learner).

Comment: @Pothi - it's encouraged to the point that you can actually check a box while asking your question to provide the answer at the same time, which is what I did. :) I could have put this info in my personal notes, but I'd rather put it on the internet where it can help others.